# Memcache "non-existent service "cache.backend.memcache" error

Tags: 8, configuration, caching

I have a successfully running and memcache.so and memcached.so and both are shown in phpinfo, I have set them in correct php.ini file and restarted all services.

```
sudo service memcached status

* memcached.service - memcached daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-02-11 22:16:41 UTC; 7min ago
 Main PID: 12367 (memcached)
    Tasks: 6
   Memory: 548.0K
      CPU: 27ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
           `-12367 /usr/bin/memcached -m 128 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
```

`settings.php`:

```
$settings['memcache']['servers'] = ['127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default'];
$settings['memcache']['bins'] = ['default' => 'default'];
$settings['memcache']['key_prefix'] = '';
$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';
```

`drush en memcache`:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "cache.backend.memcache". Did you mean one of these: "cache.backend.database", "cache.backend.apcu", "cache.backend.php", "cache.backend.memory"? in /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 157 #0 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/ChainedFastBackendFactory.php(79): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.backend.m...')
#1 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheFactory.php(83): Drupal\Core\Cache\ChainedFastBackendFactory->get('bootstrap')
#2 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheFactory->get('bootstrap')
#3 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(254): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'cache.bootstrap')
#5 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(494): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.bootstrap', 1)
#6 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(236): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array)
#7 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'module_handler')
#8 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(544): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('module_handler')
#9 /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(702): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->preHandle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#10 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php(150): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->prepareLegacyRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#11 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(354): Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->bootstrap_drupal_full()
#12 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(473): drush_bootstrap(5, 6)
#13 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(59): drush_bootstrap_to_phase(6)
#14 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#15 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(458): drush_main()
#16 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(365): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
#17 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#18 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
#19 {main}
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                  [error]
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "cache.backend.memcache". Did you mean one of these: "cache.backend.database", "cache.backend.apcu", "cache.backend.php", "cache.backend.memory"? in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 157 of /var/www/d8.com/htdocs/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).
```

So as you can see I cannot manage to enable the memcache module.

nginx php7.0-fpm

Comment: This patch works well with Drupal 9.5.x https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2429321#comment-15164180

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the memcache module *before* configuring it. The services only exist when a module is enabled.

At least with the redis module, it is also possible to manually register it to the classloader and explicitly add the services.yml file, but I don't know if that's true for memcache as well. See https://docs.platform.sh/frameworks/drupal8/redis.html

Comment: Module memcache doesn't meet the requirements to be enabled.                                                                                                                                        [error]
 (Currently using Extensions not available version Either the memcache or memcached extensions must be installed in order to use memcache integration.)

Comment: Yes, then you need to enable one of those two extensions

Comment: But they are enabled like I posted before. How do you test if they are enabled?

Comment: Well, PHP thinks they are not. Maybe you have different php.ini files for php fpm and CLI. Try php -m, try php -i and check the php.ini location

Comment: @user3108268 admin/reports/status/php will also show if either is enabled.

Comment: Yep, that's the version that will show what is enabled for the webserver. But my suspicion is that memcache *is* enabled there, but not in CLI, and @user3108268 is trying to enable the module with drush

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nlMKY4N.png

Comment: Yes, as I said above, that's your webserver. And you probably also can enable it in the UI. What's the output of php -m and what php.ini is it using?

Comment: you were right. i used find / -name php.ini and there was another one in /etc/php/7.0/cli//php.ini

Comment: Sounds like you're using Ubuntu then. You should use phpenmod memcache then, and not manually edit the php.ini files. In Ubuntu, each extension has its own ini file, which are in /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/, and then enabled for cli/apache/fpm at once through phpenmod/phpdismod.